# by (the) way: incidentally

Tags: adverbs, dictionaries, headline-english

Microsoft® Encarta® 2009. defines incidentally as

1. by way: used to introduce additional information such as something that the speaker has just thought of
2. by chance: by chance or by accident

Is the adverb by way grammatical? Otherwise, why is *the* left out? I've noticed lexicographic works do this often in brief headings such as this one, regardless of idiomaticity

Comment: I would't say it's ungrammatical (*he grunted, by way of apology, and went back to his book*) but it doesn't mean *incidentally*, and I don't think there's any justification for leaving out the *the* - I'd say it's just a mistake.

Comment: Microsoft® Encarta® 2009 is incorrect, unfortunately. The idiom is _by way **of**_. The sequence of words _by way_, used without _of_, is not a fixed phrase, nor even a constituent, and has no meaning itself. There is a noun _byway_, stressed on the first syllable, that means a small road; but that's it.

Comment: @JohnLawler but *by way of* doesn't mean *incidentally*, and isn't used "to introduce additional information such as something that the speaker has just thought of".